# JavaScript converting an array to array of functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Hello I'm working on a problem that requires me to change an set array of numbers into an array that returns the original numbers as a function. So we get a return of a2 instead of a[2].

I dont want the answer I just need a hint. I know i can loop through the array and use .pop() to get the last value of the array, but then I dont know how to convert it to a function from there. any hints?

Comment: if this is homework it should be tagged as such. it is ok if it is. just make sure you tag it

Comment: and the reason for that is: when questions are tagged w/ "homework" tag, users of the site know that coding up a full solution is not as desirable as pointing you in the right direction

Comment: Good point, I didn't really consider that. Thanks for the tip, hopefully my answer isn't going to far and is adding some knowledge! (let me know if it isn't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var numToFun = [1, 2, 3];
var numToFunLength = numToFun.length;

for (var i = 0; i < numToFunLength; i++) {
    (function(num){
        numToFun.unshift(function() {
            return num;
        });
    }(numToFun.pop())) 
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/77cr3/)

basically it pops out a number from the last, builds a function with that number returned, and put back into the first of the array. after one full cycle, all of them are functions.

here's the catch: how this works, it's up to you to research

why the loop does not look like the straightforward pop-unshift:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numToFunLength; i++) {
    numToFun.unshift(function() { //put into first a function
        return numToFun.pop()     //that returns a number
    });
}
```

and why i did this: (HINT: performance)

```
var numToFunLength = numToFun.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's three important steps here:

- Extract the number value from the array. Within a loop with an iterator of `i`, it might look like this:

  `var num = numArray[i];`
- This is important, because `i` will not retain its value that it had when you created the new function - it'll end up with the last value it had, once the `for` loop is finished. The function itself might look like this:

  `function() { return num; }`
- There's no reference to `i` any more, which is important - to understand better, read about [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). The final step would be to add the new function to the array of functions that you want.

...and you're done!

Comment: I should add, that this homework task seems to deliberately target the common mistake regarding iterators and closures. Thumbs up to the teacher/lecturer/tutor/whatever!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: See other's answers for good explanations of how to do this right, I will fix mine also though**

As others have pointed out, one of the tricky things in javascript that many struggle with (myself included, obviously) is that scoping variables in javascript is dissimilar to many other languages; scopes are almost purely defined by functions, not the {} blocks of, for example, a for loop, as java/C would be.

So, below you can see (and in other answers here) a scoping function can aid with such a problem.

```
var numArray = [12, 33, 55];
var funcArray = [];
var numArrLength = numArray.length; // Don't do this in for loop to avoid the check multiple times
for(var j=0; j < numArrLength; j++) {
    var scopeMe = function() {
        var numToReturn = numArray[j];
        console.log('now loading... ' + numToReturn);
        var newFunc = function() {
           return numToReturn;
        };
        return newFunc;
   }();
   funcArray.push(scopeMe);
};
console.log('now me');
console.log(funcArray);

console.log(funcArray[0]());
console.log(funcArray[1]());
console.log(funcArray[2]());
console.log(funcArray[1]()); // To ensure it's repeatable
```

**EDIT my old bad answer below**

What you'll want to do is something like

```
var funcArray = [];
for(...) {

   var newFunc = function() {
     return numArray.pop();

   }
   funcArray.push(newFunc); 
}
```

The key here is that functions in javascript can be named variables, and passed around as such :)

Comment: This probably won't work - `i` will be outside the `newFunc` closure, and return the last item every time.

Comment: perhaps a more generic numArray.pop(); would be better? not sure if ordering is important to the problem or not :)

Comment: I'm not really sure I deserved downvotes for that though? Can I get feedback for downvotes?

Comment: try testing in jsFiddle. you will see that the values aren't the same as you think they'd be.

Comment: The edited version still won't work - it'll return different values each time the function is called.

Comment: Yes I see, my fault OP, shouldn't try to answer problems late at night while I'm doing something else :/ Hopefully I've at least provided a good example of why you should be careful with javascript!

Comment: It stands as a good example of iterative improvement, at least ;)